# R validate library

Tags: r, validation

I know that certain column in dataframe have limited known number of possible values (missing values are allowed). I wanted to validate that using validate library. I got unexpected error:

```
library(validate)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:3, NA))
v <- validator(x %in% c(1, 2, 3, NA))
confront(df, v)
```

What is wrong with this code?

Following code works fine.

```
df$x %in% c(1, 2, 3, NA)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `validator(df$x, ...)`?

Comment: No, doesn't solve the problem, it throws the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't like the `NA`.

Even `v` is error-some already.

You can however do something like `v <- validator(x %in% c(1,2,3) | is.na(x))`

Comment: Thanks. it solves my problem, although I'm still curious why my code doesn't work.